# Why JDeveloper 12 IDE no longer supports Struts 1.2.9 framework?

Tags: jdeveloper, weblogic12c

We have a web application created using struts 1.2.9. We migrated that application to weblogic 12c. Now I want to use Jdeveloper 12 IDE for our development. So I could use the integrated weblogic 12c server. But it looks like Jdeveloper 12 no longer supports struts I framework. I had to upload the tag libraries manually and I'm not able to run the application using the IDE "Run" play button.

Getting the following error when I tried to run the application.

> The target struts-config.xml cannot be started because it is not a runnable target.

Has anyone come across a similar issue and managed to solve it?

Comment: Probably because Struts 1.x has been discontinued for 8 years now.

Comment: but shouldnt there be an option to run older applications?